# ADO Connection one or four?

Tags: delphi, ms-access, delphi-xe2, ado

I am trying to connect to a mdb (access 2000)  My App has 1 main screen with 4 buttons. each button will open a new form.

I need access to this database on all 4 of the sub forms,  Do i have to add a ADOConnection to each form?  Can i make the connection on the main form and thats it? OR is there even a better way?

Comment: one connection is the **only** approach here. with few connections you will get troubles with data update. for ex. you can execute update query with one connection, then requery data with other connection and get old dataset. of course after few seconds everythig is ok, but such synchronization between connections takes time. so you **have to** use the only one connection.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put the TADOConnection on a Data Module and USE the Data Module in all the forms to share the connection.

Open your project:

File -> New -> Other
Delphi Projects -> Delphi Files
Data Module

Then:

Project -> Options
Forms
Move the Data Module to the top of the Auto-create forms

Comment: ok did this, now i just add MyDataModule to all the forms 'uses'  Correct?

Answer (score 7):

You only need one ADOConnection that you can use from all your forms. Easiest way to share that connection is to create a data module, put the ADOConnection on that, then use the data module and its connection from all your forms. Make sure the data module is created before the forms are.

You can also put the query and table components on one or more data modules. I have found it helps promote separation between UI en data access, but that is entirely up to you.

The only reason for multiple connections is when you access a database from multiple threads. In that case you would need one connection for each thread from which you access the database.  You are doing everything from the main thread and thus only need a single connection.

Comment: "make sure the data module is created before the forms are"  in this case there not, form all ready made.. So any way to add it with out creating the 4 forms over?

Comment: lol never mind i see what your saying, make sure i create it first during runtime ,  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You must use a unique `TADOCOnnection` for the application (serving all forms).
Each form can use `TADOQuery`, `TADOTable`,...  with the main connection.

There's no reason to use 4 connections (`TADOConnection`).

Comment: little confused as you said you must use a unique TADOConnection but that there is no reason to use 4 connections?  OR you saying i can use one connection on the main, then use query/table on each form?

Comment: "You must" -> "You should". It is not a must. in fact there are situations where you must use another connection/s, for example if you use an independent thread to query your DB.

Comment: (@Glen Morse) Sorry for my mistakes on writing. I try to do as best as possible.
English is not my natural language and sometimes I have to use automatic translator to help me. Thanks.

Comment: (@kobik) What you say is correct kobik. Sometimes it's necesary use another connection, for example in the case of threads, but this is not the situation. Here we talk about 4 forms with 4 connections, in any case we speak of threads.
Even using threads, maybe it is not correct to use 4 connections (2 maybe).